# Making $ globally accessible with jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: jquery, customization

The Codex [promotes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers) this method of using `$` inside a plugin/theme JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

But if you do that you only have access to `$` inside ready(). I think functions should be broken into small modules which are called from ready(), not all lumped together inside  ready(), so if I use the Codex's method then I have to pass $ to each function, which is annoying and crude. Writing out `jQuery` all the time instead of just using `$` is also annoying.

I can just do `$ = jQuery.noConflict();` at the start of my JavaScript file and then `$` is available everywhere, but I suspect that that might cause problems with other plugins/themes in some situations. My searches haven't turned up any thorough explanations or definitive answers. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `$ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Just wrap any functions outside document.ready() within:

```
(function($){  
  // use $ here safely
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, that might work. Is there any reason to not wrap .ready() inside it too?

Comment: Also, because it creates a closure, would it [remain in memory until the page is closed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Efficiency_considerations)?

Comment: Well you can wrap the ready function too, but there's no point to do that because you'll still need to tell jQuery to run the function. So you will end up calling `jQuery.something()` anyway... I don't know about the memory usage, but I think that any function stays in memory until page changes in browser.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. If it's inside the wrapper then I can do `$(document).ready( bgmp.init );` instead of `jQuery(document).ready( bgmp.init );`, which was the whole goal. I tried it out and it's working, so I'll put off the memory issue until later. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The goal was to use `$` instead of `jQuery` only in one place from your entire script? I don't understand, do you have multiple $.ready() functions or...?

Comment: No, that was just one example; the goal was to use it everywhere possible.

Comment: Here's the updated code if that helps it make more sense: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/basic-google-maps-placemarks/tags/1.1.3/functions.js

Comment: So your plugin draws a google map based on certain data you retrieve trough wp_ajax? Can it draw multiple maps on the same page? Or this is not important in your context?

Comment: Right now it's only setup to do a single one. You could call the shortcode multiple times, but it would just overwrite the containing div.

Comment: then it's OK I guess, though your plugin doesn't really follow the typical jQuery [plugin standard](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). If you want to add support for multiple instances in the future you should organize it something like this: http://pastebin.com/RzVx8JKZ

Comment: Cool, thanks. I wouldn't really consider it a plugin for jQuery just because it uses jQuery, but it might still be a good idea to use that kind of architecture. I was under the impression that object literals were a good idea (e.g., http://www.slideshare.net/paul.irish/perfcompression slide 14), but I'll admit that I'm not really up to date on best practices for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

hope this answer can help somebody

put this code :

```
 $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

before :

```
 $(document).ready(function($){ ... });
```

Comment: The OP mentions in his question that he has reservations about this method as it might conflict with other plug-ins.